# Trying to understand Boost.Asio custom service implementation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm thinking about writing a custom Asio service on top of an existing proprietary 3rd party networking protocol that we  are currently using.

According to [Highscore Asio guide](http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/asio.html#asio_extensions) you need to implement three classes to create a custom Asio service:

- A class derived from `boost::asio::basic_io_object` representing the new I/O object.
- A class derived from `boost::asio::io_service::service` representing a service that is registered with the I/O service and can be accessed from the I/O object.
- A class not derived from any other class representing the service implementation.

The network protocol implementation already provides asynchronous operations and has a (blocking) event-loop. So I thought, I would put it into my service implementation class and run the event-loop in an internal worker thread. So far so good.

Looking at some examples of custom services, I noticed that the service classes spawn their own internal threads (in fact they instantiate their own internal io_service instances). For example:

1. The Highscore page provides a [directory monitor example](http://www.highscore.de/boost/dir_monitor.zip). It is essentially a wrapper around inotify. The interesting classes are `inotify/basic_dir_monitor_service.hpp` and `inotify/dir_monitor_impl.hpp`. `Dir_monitor_impl` handles the actual interaction with inofity, which is blocking, and therefore runs in a background thread. I agree with that. But the `basic_dir_monitor_service` also has an internal worker thread and all that seems to be doing is shuffling requests between main's `io_service` and the `dir_monitor_impl`. I played around with the code, removed the worker thread in `basic_dir_monitor_service` and instead posted requests directly to the main io_service and the program still ran as before.
2. In Asio's [custom logger service example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.services), I've noticed the same approach. The [`logger_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/services/logger_service.hpp) spawns an internal worker thread to handle the logging requests. I haven't had time to play around with that code, but I think, it should be possible to post these requests directly to the main io_service as well.

What is the advantage of having these "intermediary workers"? Couldn't you post all work to the main io_service all the time? Did I miss some crucial aspect of the Proactor pattern?

I should probably mention that I'm writing software for an underpowered single-core embedded system. Having these additional threads in place just seems to impose unnecessary context switches which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: awesome question. I was going to try my hand at that particular example one of these days. Glad to see someone else to spar with. Will read later

Comment: @sehe Wow coming from you, that means something. I've noticed your handle many times on SO. Usually answering some mind bending Boost.Spirit question

Comment: One note about inotify: it does not have to be blocking.  In fact, it's often used with epoll or select or similar.

Comment: @John Yes that is true! The inotify page says it is possible, but advises against it...but what do they know :) So, theoretically it should be possible to ditch that thread as well?

Comment: Where does it advice against using non-blocking?  I don't see anything like that in the references I checked.

Comment: @John Nevermind! I could have sworn I read that somewhere in the FAQ... wow that's embarrassing. Either way, the part I'm struggling with is the service class

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In short, consistency.  The services attempt to meet user expectations set forth by the services Boost.Asio provides.

Using an internal `io_service` provides a clear separation of ownership and control of handlers.  If a custom service posts its internal handlers into the user's `io_service`, then execution of the service's internal handlers becomes implicitly coupled with the user's handlers.  Consider how this would impact user expectations with the [Boost.Asio Logger Service](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.services) example:

- The `logger_service` writes to the file stream within a handler.  Thus, a program that never processes the `io_service` event loop, such as one that only uses the synchronous API, would never have log messages written.
- The `logger_service` would no longer be thread-safe, potentially invoking undefined behavior if the `io_service` is processed by multiple threads.
- The lifetime of the `logger_service`'s internal operations is constrained by that of the `io_service`.  For example, when a service's `shutdown_service()` function is invoked, the lifetime of the owning `io_service` has already ended.  Hence, messages could not be logged via `logger_service::log()` within `shutdown_service()`, as it would attempt to post an internal handler into the `io_service` whose lifetime has already ended.
- The user may no longer assume a one-to-one mapping between an operation and handler.  For example:

  ```
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  debug_stream_socket socket(io_service);
  boost::asio::async_connect(socket, ..., &connect_handler);
  io_service.poll();
  // Can no longer assume connect_handler has been invoked.
  ```

  In this case, `io_service.poll()` may invoke the handler internal to the `logger_service`, rather than `connect_handler()`.

Furthermore, these internal threads attempt to mimic the behavior used internally by Boost.Asio [itself](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html#boost_asio.overview.core.threads.internal_threads):

> The implementation of this library for a particular platform may make use of one or more internal threads to emulate asynchronicity. As far as possible, these threads must be invisible to the library user.

---

#### [Directory Monitor example](http://www.highscore.de/boost/dir_monitor.zip)

In the directory monitor example, an internal thread is used to prevent indefinitely blocking the user's `io_service` while waiting for an event.  Once an event has occurred, the completion handler is ready to be invoked, so the internal thread post the user handler into the user's `io_service` for deferred invocation.  This implementation emulates asynchronicity with an internal thread that is mostly invisible to the user.

For details, when an asynchronous monitor operation is initiated via `dir_monitor::async_monitor()`, a `basic_dir_monitor_service::monitor_operation` is posted into the internal `io_service`.  When invoked, this operation invokes `dir_monitor_impl::popfront_event()`, a potentially blocking call.  Hence, if the `monitor_operation` is posted into the user's `io_service`, the user's thread could be indefinitely blocked.  Consider the affect on the following code:

```cpp
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::dir_monitor dir_monitor(io_service); 
dir_monitor.add_directory(dir_name); 
// Post monitor_operation into io_service.
dir_monitor.async_monitor(...);
io_service.post(&user_handler);
io_service.run();
```

In the above code, if `io_service.run()` invokes `monitor_operation` first, then `user_handler()` will not be invoked until `dir_monitor` observes an event on the `dir_name` directory.  Therefore, `dir_monitor` service's implementation would not behave in a consistent manner that most users expect from other services.

#### [Asio Logger Service](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.services)

The use of an internal thread and `io_service`:

- Mitigates the overhead of logging on the user's thread(s) by performing potentially blocking or expensive calls within the internal thread.
- Guarantees the thread-safety of `std::ofstream`, as only the single internal thread writes to the stream.  If logging was done directly within `logger_service::log()` or if `logger_service` posted its handlers into the user's `io_service`, then explicit synchronization would be required for thread-safety.  Other synchronization mechanisms may introduce greater overhead or complexity into the implementation.
- Allows for [`services`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Service.html) to log messages within [`shutdown_service()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__service/shutdown_service.html).  During [destruction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/_io_service.html), the `io_service` will:

  1. Shutdown each of its services.
  2. Destroy all uninvoked handlers that were scheduled for deferred invocation in the `io_service` or any of its associated `strand`s.
  3. Destroy each of its services.

  As the lifetime of the user's `io_service` has ended, its event queue is neither being processed nor can additional handlers be posted.  By having its own internal `io_service` that is processed by its own thread, `logger_service` enables other services to log messages during their `shutdown_service()`.

---

#### Additional Considerations

When implementing a custom service, here are a few points to consider:

- Block all signals on internal threads.
- Never invoke the user's code directly.
- How to track and post user handlers when an implementation is destroyed.
- Resource(s) owned by the service that are shared between the service's implementations.

For the last two points, the `dir_monitor` I/O object exhibits behavior that users may not expect.  As the single thread within the service invokes a blocking operation on a single implementation's event queue, it effectively blocks operations that could potentially complete immediately for their respective implementation:

```cpp
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::dir_monitor dir_monitor1(io_service); 
dir_monitor1.add_directory(dir_name1); 
dir_monitor1.async_monitor(&handler_A);

boost::asio::dir_monitor dir_monitor2(io_service); 
dir_monitor2.add_directory(dir_name2); 
dir_monitor2.async_monitor(&handler_B);
// ... Add file to dir_name2.

{
  // Use scope to enforce lifetime.
  boost::asio::dir_monitor dir_monitor3(io_service); 
  dir_monitor3.add_directory(dir_name3); 
  dir_monitor3.async_monitor(&handler_C);
}
io_service.run();
```

Although the operations associated with `handler_B()` (success) and `handler_C()` (aborted) would not block, the single thread in `basic_dir_monitor_service` is blocked waiting for a change to `dir_name1`.